# Beginner Java Minesweeper Game

Tags: java, beginner, minesweeper

I made a Minesweeper game in Java 8, but I am not sure if the code is any good. Comments and questions are in the code.

Here's the code on [Github](https://github.com/ym1234/Minesweeper) (not commented though).

Game.java:

Main Class of the game, handles input and output and a number of other things (I am not sure whether I should remove this class or not).

```
import java.util.*;

public class Game {

Board board;

public Game(int length, int width,int numOfMines) {

    board = new Board(length, width, numOfMines);

    help();

    // First choice isn't guaranteed to be safe
    // TODO: generate the board when the user makes his first choice ( to make sure it's safe )

    System.out.println("Generating Board");

    start();

}

public void start() {
    while (true) {
        userInput();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // currently doesn't check if  numOfMines > (length*width)

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Length: ");
    int length = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Width: ");
   int width =  scan.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Number Of Mines: ");
    int numOfMines = scan.nextInt();

    new Game(length,width,numOfMines);
}


public void help() {
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Commands:");
    System.out.println("           \"help\" opens the help menu");
    System.out.println("           \"choose\" specify which tile you want to check");
    System.out.println("           \"flag\" specify which tile you want to flag");
    System.out.println("           \"restart\" start a new game");
    System.out.println("           \"quit\" to quit the game");
    System.out.println();
}

// handles user input (not sure if this is the best way to handle it)
// there is a lot of exceptions that can be caught here but I'm leaving them for now

void userInput() {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("$ ");
    String userInput;

    userInput = scan.nextLine();
    userInput = userInput.trim().toLowerCase();

    int row;
    int column;

    switch (userInput)
    {
        case "help":

            help();
            break;

        case "choose":

            System.out.print("Row: ");
            row = scan.nextInt() - 1;

            System.out.print("Column: ");
            column = scan.nextInt() - 1;

            choose(row, column);
            board.printBoard();
            break;

        case "restart":

            // currently doesn't check if  numOfMines > (length*width)
            System.out.print("Length: ");
            int length = scan.nextInt();

            System.out.print("Width: ");
            int width =  scan.nextInt();

            System.out.print("Number Of Mines: ");
            int numOfMines = scan.nextInt();

            restart(length, width, numOfMines);
            break;

        case "flag":

            System.out.print("Row: ");
            row = scan.nextInt()-1;

            System.out.print("Column: ");
            column =  scan.nextInt()-1;

            flag(row, column);
            board.printBoard();
            break;

        case "quit":

            scan.close();
            System.exit(0);

        case "":
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid input");
            break;
    }
}

// checks Input:
// if the cell is  a mine then the user losses( not implemented yet)
// if it has a value( value>0 ) then it reveals the cell then prints the board
// if the cell doesn't have a value it (value == 0)  then it calls reveal()

void choose(int row, int column) {
    Cell cell = board.getBoard()[row][column];
    if (cell.isMine()) {
        board.printBoard();
        System.out.println("Lose");
    } else if (cell.hasValue()) {
        cell.show();
        board.printBoard();
    } else if (!cell.hasValue()) {
        reveal(cell, new ArrayList<>(), new ArrayList<>(),0);
    }
}

// queue contains empty cells that hasn't been processed ( processing means checking its surroundingCells )
// adds the Cells to the queue(DOESN'T ADD THEM IF THEY'RE IN THE "PROCESSED" ARRAYLIST) (and reveals it) if their value is equal to "0"(Empty)
// if their value > 0 (and not a mine) then it just reveals them
// if the cell is a mine it doesn't reveal them
// should returns if queue.isEmpty
// TODO: Bug: returns in a weird way.

public void reveal(Cell cell, ArrayList<Cell> queue, ArrayList<Cell> processed,Integer i) {

    // debugging( number of recursions )
    i++;

    cell.show();

    if (queue.isEmpty()) {
        ArrayList<Cell> surroudingCells = cell.getSurroundingCells();
        for (Cell cell2 : surroudingCells) {
            if (!cell2.hasValue() && !cell.isMine()) {
                queue.add(cell2);
            } else if (cell2.hasValue()) {
                cell2.show();
            }
        }

        if (queue.isEmpty()) {

        } else {
            reveal(queue.get(0), queue, processed, i);
        }
    } else {
        for (Cell cell2 : cell.getSurroundingCells()) {
            if (queue.contains(cell2)) {

            } else if (processed.contains(cell2)) {

            } else if (!cell2.hasValue() && !cell2.isMine()) {
                queue.add(cell2);
            } else if (cell2.hasValue()) {
                cell2.show();
            } else if (cell2.isShown()) {

            } else if (cell2.isMine()) {

            }
        }

        processed.add(cell);
        queue.remove(cell);

        if (queue.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        } else {
            reveal(queue.get(0), queue, processed,i);
        }
    }
    // Debugging
    board.printBoard();
    System.out.println(i);
}

// sets isFlagged to true/false depending on its state

void flag(int row, int column) {

    Cell cell = board.getBoard()[row][column];
    cell.setFlagged(!cell.isFlagged());

}


// creates a new board

void restart(int length, int width, int numOfMines) {
    System.out.println("Generating new Board");
    board = new Board(length, width, numOfMines);
}
}
```

Board.java: Represents the board.

Creates an array filled with `Cell`s, handles the properties of each cell, used by Game.java to communicate with cells.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Board {

private final int width;
private final int length;
private final int numOfMines;

private Cell[][] board;


public Board(int length, int width, int numOfMines) {

    this.width = width;
    this.length = length;
    this.numOfMines = numOfMines;

    board = new Cell[length][width];
    generate();
}

private void generate() {
    generateMines();
    generateNumbers();
    printSolvedBoard();
}

// creates a new cell that has a chance of being a mine (0.00001) ( The chance is low because I'm afraid that only the first few Cells are going to become mines)
// doesn't stop until there are the amount of mines specified by Game.java ( user )
// This is inefficient(loops the array 20000-30000 times when the number of mines = 20), I'm sure there is a better way to do this.


private void generateMines() {

    int currentNumOfMines = 0;
    Random random = new Random();


    while (currentNumOfMines < numOfMines) {

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {

                double probability = random.nextDouble();

                if (board[i][j] == null) {
                    board[i][j] = new Cell(i, j, false, board.clone());
                } else if (board[i][j].isMine()) {

                } else if (probability > 0.99999 && currentNumOfMines < numOfMines) {
                    board[i][j] = new Cell(i, j, true, board.clone());
                    currentNumOfMines++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Calls Cell.setValue() method on every Cell in the board

private void generateNumbers() {
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            if (board[i][j].isMine()) {

            } else {
                board[i][j].setValue();
            }
        }
    }
}
public void printBoard() {

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            if (board[i][j].isMine()) {

            }
            System.out.print(" " + board[i][j].getSymbol());
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public void printSolvedBoard() {

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            if (board[i][j].isMine()) {

            }
            System.out.print(" " + board[i][j].getValue());
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

// I am not sure if I am overriding these correctly (hashCode(),equals())

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return width * length * numOfMines + 13;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    Board boardObj = (Board) obj;
    return Arrays.deepEquals(boardObj.getBoard(), board);
}

public int getWidth() {
    return width;
}

public int getLength() {
    return length;
}

public int getNumOfMines() {
    return numOfMines;
}

public Cell[][] getBoard() {
    return board;
}
}
```

Cell.java:

Represents the `Cell`. Knows its position in the array, whether it is a mine or not, whether it is flagged/shown or not and it also has a clone of the array it is in (I'm not sure if that is a good idea).

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Cell {

// the Cells Position

private final int xPos;
private final int yPos;

// the Cells Properties
private final boolean isMine;
private boolean isFlagged;
private boolean isShown;

private String symbol;
private String value;

// the Cell's surroundings

private Cell[][] myBoard;
private ArrayList<Cell> surrondingCells;

public Cell(int x, int y, boolean isMine, Cell[][] board) {

    this.isMine = isMine;
    this.isFlagged = false;
    this.isShown = false;

    this.myBoard = board;
    surrondingCells = new ArrayList<>();

    this.xPos = x;
    this.yPos = y;
    symbol = "*";

    if (this.isMine) {
        value = "#";
    }
}

public boolean isMine() {
    return isMine;
}

public int getxPos() {
    return xPos;
}

public int getyPos() {
    return yPos;
}

public String getSymbol() {
    return symbol;
}

public void show() {
    symbol = value;
    isShown = true;
}

public boolean isShown() {
    return isShown;
}

public boolean hasValue() {

    if (isMine == true) return false;

    return Integer.parseInt(value) > 0;
}

public ArrayList<Cell> getSurroundingCells() {

    if (surrondingCells.isEmpty()) {
        setSurroundingCells();
    }

    return surrondingCells;
}

private void setSurroundingCells() {
    for (int i = xPos - 1; i <= xPos + 1; i++) {
        for (int j = yPos - 1; j <= yPos + 1; j++) {

            if (i == xPos && j == yPos) {

            } else {
                try {
                    surrondingCells.add(myBoard[i][j]);
                } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public String getValue() {
    return value;
}


// gets the surroundingCells from getSurroundingCells() then checks the number of mines in the ArrayList

public void setValue() {

    if (isMine) {
        return;
    }

    // if the board contains null then the method will exist (to avoid errors)

    if (Arrays.asList(myBoard).contains(null)) {
        return;
    }

    int surroundingMines = 0;

    for (Cell cell : getSurroundingCells()) {
        if (cell.isMine()) {
            surroundingMines++;
        }
    }

    value = Integer.toString(surroundingMines);
}

public boolean isFlagged() {
    return isFlagged;
}

public void setFlagged(boolean flagged) {
    isFlagged = flagged;

    if (isShown) {
        return;
    } else if (isFlagged) {
        symbol = "F";
    } else {
        if (isMine) {
            symbol = "#";
        } else if (isShown) {
            symbol = value;
        } else {
            symbol = "*";
        }
    }
}

// I am not sure if I am overriding these correctly (hashCode(),equals())

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return xPos * yPos * symbol.hashCode() * value.hashCode() * 29 + 6;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    Cell cell = (Cell) obj;
    return cell.getyPos() == yPos && cell.getxPos() == xPos && cell.isMine() == isMine && cell.getValue().equals(value);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "X: " + xPos + " Y: " + yPos + " Value:" + value;
}

}
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Redundant fields

> ```
> private final int width;
> private final int length;
> ```

You do not need these.

> ```
>     this.width = width;
>     this.length = length;
> ```

Nor here.

> ```
> public int getWidth() {
>     return width;
> }
>
> public int getLength() {
>     return length;
> }
> ```

These could be

```
public int getWidth() {
    return board[0].length;
}

public int getLength() {
    return board.length;
}
```

Now you're guaranteed consistency with the `board`.

> ```
>         for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
>             for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
> ```

can become

```
        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
```

Again, this ensures that you never overshoot the `board` dimensions.

#### `hashCode`/`equals`

> ```
> // I am not sure if I am overriding these correctly (hashCode(),equals())
>
> @Override
> public int hashCode() {
>     return width * length * numOfMines + 13;
> }
>
> @Override
> public boolean equals(Object obj) {
>     Board boardObj = (Board) obj;
>     return Arrays.deepEquals(boardObj.getBoard(), board);
> }
> ```

These are not consistent with each other.  The rule of thumb is that if two objects are equal, then the `hashCode` values for both should be equal.  If the `hashCode` values are equal, then the objects should usually be equal.

Example source:  [Best implementation for hashCode method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/113511/6660678)

Simplest implementation if you are using Java 5 or newer:

```
public int hashCode() {
    return Arrays.deepHashCode(board);
}
```

This makes the two methods consistent.  Both are based on the values of `board`.

But what if `obj` in `equals` is not a `Board`?

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    // if obj is the same object as this, no need to process more
    if (obj == this) {
        return true;
    }

    // if obj is null, then it can't equal this
    // if obj is a different class than this, then they can't be equal
    if (obj == null || obj.getClass() != getClass()) {
        return false;
    }

    Board boardObj = (Board) obj;
    return Arrays.deepEquals(boardObj.getBoard(), board);
}
```

No need to waste time if we're talking about the same object, not just two potentially equivalent objects.

Now we won't have any exceptions because someone tried to check equality of a `Board` with a `Cell`.

Example source:  [How to override equals method in java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8180430/6660678)

Note that that source offers some more complex examples.  For example, it handles the case where you might have some other class extend `Board`.  I didn't do that here, as your current example doesn't need it.

> ```
> public int hashCode() {
>     return xPos * yPos * symbol.hashCode() * value.hashCode() * 29 + 6;
> }
> ```

So if you're using Java 7 or newer, you can say

```
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(yPos, xPos, isMine, value);
}
```

Now it will be consistent with your `equals` implementation (which has the same issues as the one for `Board`, which I won't repeat).

If compiling against an older Java, you could do a custom implementation like

```
public int hashCode() {
    int result = 6;

    result = 29 * result + yPos;
    result = 29 * result + xPos;
    result = 29 * result + (isMine ? 0 : 1);
    result = 29 * result + ((value == null) ? 0 : value.hashCode());

    return result;
}
```

Again, note that this uses the same fields as the `equals` method.

Comment: Thank you for you review, but I really wanted to know your opinion on Game.class.
It is the one I'm most unsatisfied with.